# "java.lang.SecurityException:Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission" error on multiple activities workflow testing android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-activity, android-testing

In my code I have `HomeActivity.java`. In this Activity I have 3 image buttons and when I click any of the button it opens a new activity (`ItemListActivity`) with `intent.putExtra`.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("for", "files");
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);)**
```

Here's the full code:

```
public class HomeActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity> {

    private HomeActivity homeActivity;
    ImageView ivFiles;
    ImageView ivForms;
    ImageView ivModels;
    private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 5000;
    private Intent mLaunchIntent;

    public HomeActivityTest() {
        super(HomeActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        try {
            /**
             * Using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
             */

            setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
            CommonUtilities.createSharedPreferenceEditor(getInstrumentation().getContext());
            homeActivity = getActivity();
            ivFiles = (ImageView) homeActivity.findViewById(R.id.ivFilesBtn);
            ivForms = (ImageView) homeActivity.findViewById(R.id.ivFormsBtn);
            ivModels = (ImageView) homeActivity.findViewById(R.id.ivModelBtn);

            assertNotNull("HomeActivity is null", homeActivity);
            assertNotNull("File Image is null",ivFiles);
            assertNotNull("File Image is null",ivForms);
            assertNotNull("File Image is null",ivModels);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @MediumTest
    public void testOpenItemListActivity(){

        Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor1 = getInstrumentation()
                .addMonitor(ItemListActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

        /*
            When I click on this ivFiles in HomeActivity, it Opens new ItemListActivity.

                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("for", "files");
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
         */
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, ivFiles);

        ItemListActivity itemListActivity1 = (ItemListActivity) receiverActivityMonitor1
                .waitForActivityWithTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MS);

        assertNotNull("ItemListActivity is null", itemListActivity1);
        assertEquals("Monitor for ReceiverActivity has not been called", 1,
                receiverActivityMonitor1.getHits());
        assertEquals("Activity is of wrong type", ItemListActivity.class,
                itemListActivity1.getClass());

        assertEquals("Wrong data pass on ivFiles Click", itemListActivity1.dataToOpen, "files");

        getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(receiverActivityMonitor1);

        receiverActivityMonitor1 = getInstrumentation()
                .addMonitor(ItemListActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
        /*
            When I click on this ivFiles in HomeActivity, it Opens new ItemListActivity.

                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("for", "files");
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
         */

        TouchUtils.clickView(this, ivModels);

        ItemListActivity itemListActivity2 = (ItemListActivity) receiverActivityMonitor1
                .waitForActivityWithTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MS);

        assertNotNull("ItemListActivity is null", itemListActivity2);
        assertEquals("Monitor for ReceiverActivity has not been called", 1,
                receiverActivityMonitor1.getHits());
        assertEquals("Activity is of wrong type", ItemListActivity.class,
                itemListActivity1.getClass());

        assertEquals("Wrong data pass on ivModels Click", itemListActivity2.dataToOpen, "models");

        getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(receiverActivityMonitor1);

    }
    }
```

I have written a test case for this `HomeActivity` that is `HomeActivityTest.java`. But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

So how should I test this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this if the device on a build server is locked and the screen is not accessible.

Comment: I want to test a scenario where in an activity there are 3 buttons. And on click of each button opens different activity using intent. How can I test this type of scenario using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Comment: See what I posted on Yeehaw's answer

Answer (score -2):

Did you add the actual permission to your manifest file?

It's `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>`.

Comment: I want to test a scenario where in an activity there are 3 buttons. And on click of each button opens different activity using intent. How can I test this type of scenario using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Comment: Are you using Robotium?  I tend to follow something like: `assertTrue(getSolo().waitForView(getSolo().getView(R.id.view_id));getSolo().clickOnView(getSolo().getView(R.id.view_id)); assertTrue(getSolo().waitForActivity(NextActivity.class));`

Comment: Also, for getSolo() I have a class that extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 that has a private variable for solo so: `private Solo mSolo;` and my getSolo() method is: `protected Solo getSolo() {
        if (mSolo == null) {
            mSolo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        }
        return mSolo;
    }` Hope that helps

Comment: only granted for system apps